# How to search in acending order in datatables plugin

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using datatables plugin to show the data and the data is displaying in descending order by default. But when i am going to search it gives the result in asceding order and disturbed the display order of data as it gives the result in ascending order.
Thanks in advance

```js
 var dTable = $('.MemberListTable').DataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "bSortable": false,
                "lengthChange": true,
                "bRetrieve": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": true,
                // "responsive": true,
                "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75], [25, 50, 75]]
            });
            dTable.order([[6, 'asc']]).draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dTable = $('.MemberListTable').DataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "bSortable": false,
                "lengthChange": true,
                "bRetrieve": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": true,
                "order" : [[columnNumber(in your case it is 6) , 'asc']],
                // "responsive": true,
                "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75], [25, 50, 75]]
            });
```

It will make it by default in ascending order. 
If you want results in descending order than add this in your searching logic:

```
dTable.order([[columnNumber, 'desc']]).draw();
```

Actually , I really don't understand what you are asking.
If helpful , you are welcome in advance.

Otherwise, you should see this.
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/26765/change-sort-order-after-search#Comment_72992

Comment: i just want first time data should be display in descending order by default. But when i am going to search it should gives the result in ascending order and a part from this when the page will be reload data data should display in descending order as earlier.

Comment: first of all i would like to thank you. But when i am passing the column no i.e dTable.order([[6, 'desc']]).draw(); it disturbes the by default display order as data is displaying in improper order.

Comment: See the updated answer I have given a link if it helps

Comment: I am extramly sorry for mis understanding . I just want at the page load data shoould be in descending order. But when i am going to search this search should be apply on entire columns of table and should gives the result in ascending order.